# How to make osm2po 5.1 write an SQL file?

Tags: osm2po

With osm2po 5.1, I can get the osm2po router running

```
D:\osm2po-5.1.0>java -Xmx1024m -jar osm2po-core-5.1.0-signed.jar 
prefix=vie ..\vienna_austria.osm.pbf
```

but the resuting `vie` folder only contains the osm2po graph .gph and no .sql file for import into PostGIS. I don't get any warnings and couldn't find any new instructions in the documentation related to writing .sql files.

In 5.0, the .sql file is created as expected.

Comment: Running 5.1, I have the same problem as the OP (folder contains only .gph and 2po files) and have tried both Carsten and Steven's suggestions for the .config file mods, without the success that Anita had - ie Still no sql. I've also tried the settings for postp.pipeOut. Interestingly I DO get a warning in the log file, stating that "WARN cmd 'p' set but no postprocessors injected" So clearly PgRoutingWriter can't produce something if it is not being invoked (despite being tasked), but being a newbie I'm at a loss to know why, sorry! (PS I realise that this is not a solution to OP problem but t

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Spotted this under the release notes

> The PgRoutingWriter has moved to the osm2po-plugins.jar which is open
>   source. The writer is not enabled by default anymore. If needed,
>   please edit (uncomment) the corresponding line in the osm2po.config or
>   add it to the command line call.

If you update your config file to remove the comment hashes from this block of lines, it generates the .sql file

```
postp.0.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgRoutingWriter
postp.0.writeMultiLineStrings = true
postp.1.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgVertexWriter
postp.2.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgPolyWayWriter
postp.3.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgPolyRelWriter

postp.4.class = de.cm.osm2po.postp.GeoExtensionBuilder
postp.5.class = de.cm.osm2po.postp.MlgExtensionBuilder
postp.5.id = 0
postp.5.maxLevel = 3, 1.0

postp.6.class = de.cm.osm2po.sd.postp.SdGraphBuilder

# Pg*Writer usually create sql files. Enable the following
# parameter to redirect them to stdout (console)

postp.pipeOut = false
```

Comment: Thanks Steven! Makes sense reading your instructions now.

Comment: It is sufficient to enable (uncomment) this line only: `postp.0.class = de.cm.osm2po.plugins.postp.PgRoutingWriter`

Comment: In osm2po 5.2.9 I got a `de.cm.osm2po.sd.postp.SdGraphBuilder not found` warning ... Is it important? ( It was changed to `postp.7.class` )

Comment: @MagnoC see Carsten's comment above - you should only need the one line (IIRC, Carsten is author of osm2po) so try commenting out any which give exceptions.

Comment: How can I append or update data ?